# How the get paths and names pf APKs build with `gradlew`?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Assume I build a debug and test APK with `gradlew` for a standard Android project, created using one of the Android Studio templates, using this command:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest
```

This creates files in the following locations:

- `app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`
- `app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk`

Does `gradlew` somehow expose those 2 paths and filenames?

---

[Android Studio docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode) supposedly describes how the path is constructed:

> To initiate a debug build, invoke the `assembleDebug` task:
>    `gradlew assembleDebug`
>   This creates an APK named `module_name-debug.apk` in `project_name/module_name/build/outputs/apk/`

but this obviously doesn't match for any of my files, especially not for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

the `./gradlew` is just a wrapper, but in a `build.gradle` one can access them:

```
// root project build.gradle
project.ext.set('archiveBuildTypes', ['release', 'debug'])

// module-level build.gradle
android {
    getRootProject().each {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                if (variant.getBuildType().getName() in rootProject.archiveBuildTypes) {
                    def buildType = variant.getBuildType().getName()
                    if (variant.versionName != null) {

                        // baseName is the base filename
                        def baseName = output.baseName

                        // perform some string-manipulation here, if required

                        // outputFileName is the file-name being actually used:
                        String fileName = "someapp_${variant.versionName}-${baseName}.apk"
                        outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, fileName).getName()

                        println(outputFileName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if it is required to obtain the values with `./gradlew`, you could simply wrap that up into a custom Gradle task, whose name can then be passed as a command-line argument. it may look a little strange, that `outputFileName` is not being defined within that scope, but it is known in there.

Comment: Wow, interesting! Is there a way to "inject" that into a project without modifying its `build.gradle` file? As a "param" to the `gradlew` command?

Comment: one can add a `tasks.gradle` and then `apply from: 'tasks.gradle'` in the `build.gradle` (this is how I manage those scripts) ...Gradle scripts do belong into a `build.gradle`, because `./gradlew` does not care about any other files.